# How to handle missing records of a Product's attribute value in laravel 7

Tags: laravel, eloquent

**Background Information:**

I'm learning laravel 7 by creating an inventory system.
I have several models: Product, Stock, and Attribute.

- The **Product** is like a group that holds all of the stock. Because I can have a Product like a speaker. But I can have many quantities of that same product that have different attribute values. This is when the Stock becomes important.
- The **Stock** is where I have all of the items in my inventory.

  - For example: If I have 20 speakers, there will be one record in the products table and 20 records in the stocks table.
- The **Attribute** is because I want to track different attributes depending on the Product. But the value of those attributes doesn't belong to the product; It belongs to the Stock of the product.

This is how my models relate:

- A Product hasMany Stock
- A Stock belongsTo a Product
- A Product hasMany Attribute
- An Attribute belongsTo a Product
- An Attribute belongsToMany Stock
- A Stock belongsToMany Attribute (I'm not very confident about this one.)

---

**Goal:**

[image: My expected outcome]

The **Product** is **L-Acoustics LA12X**

The product's **Attributes** are **Serial Number** and **Firmware**

The product's **Stock** is the card that says "Stock Level".

For testing and simplicity, I copied the same values of Serial Number and Firmware to all of the Product's Stock; but in real life they should all have different serial numbers and firmware versions.

---

**Problem:**

I only get the output from the picture above when there is a value for each attribute. For example: if I delete the attribute value of the Serial Number from the first stock I get this.
[image]

Do you see how it shifted the Firmware value to the Serial Numbers column?

In the case that the record is deleted or the value hasn't been created I would like to put an empty cell in that table so that it looks like this. (I created this image by editing the HTML of the page, I still don't know how to get this output)

[image]

---

**What I have tried:**

I quickly thought of creating empty cells in my database belonging to the attribute so that when I loop through my records I get a perfect table. But this will quickly become a problem when my database increases size.

You could think of why would there be records that don't exist? Well one example is that my inventory is so old that there are some Serial Numbers that I can't retrieve. Therefore, there will be no records in the table.

**Showing some code:**

This is my database design: [image: Databse Desing]

This is my Product Model:

```
class Product extends Model {
    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $casts = [
        'brand_id'     => 'integer',
        'category_id'  => 'integer',
        'price'        => 'decimal:2',
        'rental_price' => 'decimal:2',
        'active'       => 'boolean'
    ];

    public function setNameAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['name'] = $value;
        $this->attributes['slug'] = Str::slug($value);
    }

    public function brand()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);
    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

    public function stocks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Stock::class)->orderBy('barcode', 'asc');
    }

    public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Attribute::class);
    }

}
```

This is my Stock Model:

```
class Stock extends Model {
    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $casts = [
        'quantity'     => 'integer',
        'product_id'   => 'integer',
    ];

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }

    public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Attribute::class)->withPivot('value');
    }
}
```

This is my Attribute Model:

```
class Attribute extends Model {
    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $casts = ['product_id' => 'integer'];

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }

    public function stocks()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Stock::class);
    }

    public function values()
    {
        // This method is empty because I don't know how to relate the attribute to its values.
    }
```

I know I have dumped a lot of information but I really need help. I have an open mind and I'm open to new implementations.

---

**UPDATE**

Here is the code of my view:

```html
<div class="block-content block-content-full">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-borderless table-striped table-vcenter font-size-sm">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-left">Barcode</th>
                    @foreach($product->attributes as $attribute)
                        <th class="text-center">{{ $attribute->name }}</th>
                    @endforeach
                    <th class="text-right">Condition</th>
                    <th class="text-right">Updated</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @forelse($product->stocks as $stock)
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-left">
                            <a href="{{ route('products.stocks.show', [$product->slug, strtolower($stock->barcode)]) }}"><strong>{{ $stock->barcode }}</strong></a>
                        </td>
                        @foreach($stock->attributes as $attribute)
                            <td class="text-center">{{ $attribute->pivot->value }}</td>
                        @endforeach
                        <td class="text-right">
                            @switch($stock->condition)
                                @case('Great')
                                <span class="badge badge-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle mr-1"></i>Great</span>
                                @break
                                @case('Damaged')
                                <span class="badge badge-warning"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle mr-1"></i>Damage</span>
                                @break
                                @case('Broken')
                                <span class="badge badge-danger"><i class="fa fa-times-circle mr-1"></i>Broken</span>
                                @break
                            @endswitch
                        </td>
                        <td class="text-right">{{ $stock->updated_at->format('M d, Y') }}</td>
                    </tr>
                @empty
                    <tr><td colspan="100" class="text-center">No Stock Available</td></tr>
                @endforelse
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the show method in my controller:

```php
public function show(Product $product)
{
    return view('products.show', compact('product'));
}
```

---

**UPDATE 2:**

I updated my Attribute model to this:

```php
class Attribute extends Model {
    protected $guarded = [];

    protected $casts = ['product_id' => 'integer'];

    public function getValueByBarcode($stock)
    {
        return $this->values()->where('barcode', $stock)->first()->value ?? '';
    }

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }

    public function stocks()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Stock::class);
    }

    public function values()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Stock::class)->select('value');
    }
}
```

and in my blade I got the values like this:

```html
<table class="table table-borderless table-striped table-vcenter font-size-sm">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-left">Barcode</th>
            @foreach($product->attributes as $attribute)
                <th class="text-center">{{ $attribute->name }}</th>
            @endforeach
            <th class="text-right">Condition</th>
            <th class="text-right">Updated</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @forelse($product->stocks as $stock)
            <tr>
                <td class="text-left">
                    <a href="{{ route('products.stocks.show', [$product->slug, strtolower($stock->barcode)]) }}"><strong>{{ $stock->barcode }}</strong></a>
                </td>
                @foreach($product->attributes as $attribute)
                    <td class="text-center">{{ $attribute->getValueByBarcode($stock->barcode) }}</td>
                @endforeach
                <td class="text-right">
                    @switch($stock->condition)
                        @case('Great')
                        <span class="badge badge-success"><i class="fa fa-check-circle mr-1"></i>Great</span>
                        @break
                        @case('Damaged')
                        <span class="badge badge-warning"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle mr-1"></i>Damage</span>
                        @break
                        @case('Broken')
                        <span class="badge badge-danger"><i class="fa fa-times-circle mr-1"></i>Broken</span>
                        @break
                    @endswitch
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">{{ $stock->updated_at->format('M d, Y') }}</td>
            </tr>
        @empty
            <tr><td colspan="100" class="text-center">No Stock Available</td></tr>
        @endforelse
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the result of that change

[image: Expected Outcome]

I finally managed to get what I wanted but is there a cleaner way of doing the same thing?

Comment: I think the important part is your view, and it's missing, you can do your display logic directly there.

Comment: You have provided a lot of information, that's great. But the issue likely lies with your blade template view, you probably need some conditional logic there to include an empty cell even when there is no data for that field. Please add code for your view template and for completeness also your controller.

Comment: @ChristopheHubert I have Updated the post with the view and controller

Comment: @Andrew I have Updated the post with the view and controller

Comment: You problem is you assume that `$product->attributes` is the same as your `$stock->attributes` but you will end up having issues, if the order of column is different or in your case if the attribute is empty

Comment: @ChristopheHubert I ordered them by the attribute_id so they will match. My only problem is when the value doesn't exist. Do you know how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would use [keyBy](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-keyby) on your collection of stock attributes (Untested)

```
@php($s_attributes = $stock->attributes->keyBy('attribute_id'))
@foreach($product->attributes as $p_attribute)
    <td class="text-center">{{ isset($s_attributes[$p_attribute->id]) ? $s_attributes[$p_attribute->id]->pivot->value : ''}}</td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I edited the question with the code that got me the desired output and it is something similar to this. I took out the logic from the blade and put it in the Model. But my question is, Is there a cleaner of accomplishing what I did?